# Kit Assembly Release throwing "Another Process has updated" message?

Tags: acumatica

Today's fun:
Have a processing screen that does a bunch of things
May create/release:
    One Step Transfer
    IN 2 step transfer
    SO 2 step transfer
    PO Receipt
    Kit Assembly

Fun part #1:  Release can't (apparently) be within the transaction

So, it goes through fine, up until the release of the kit assembly.

- First run:  Throws the error
- second run, no code changed:  Succeeds
- If try to release through the Kit assembly screen manually, works
- If try to release through the IN Doc release, works

Yet, I keep getting:

```
2018-08-23 19:07:16Z [23] Error w3wp.exe 0: 23803b8a-d4f4-4523-b310-a6ddd16bc3bd 100035 PX.Data.PXOperationCompletedSingleErrorException: Error: Another process has updated the 'INRegister' record. Your changes will be lost. ---> PX.Data.PXLockViolationException: Error: Another process has updated the 'INRegister' record. Your changes will be lost.
   at PX.Data.PXTableAttribute.PersistUpdated(PXCache sender, Object row)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistUpdated(Object row)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()
   at PX.Objects.IN.INReleaseProcess.ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, INRegister doc)
   at PX.Objects.IN.INReleaseProcess.ReleaseDocProcR(JournalEntry je, INRegister doc)
   at PX.Objects.IN.INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(List`1 list, Boolean isMassProcess)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PX.Objects.IN.INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(List`1 list, Boolean isMassProcess)
   at MaxQ.Products.SupplyChain.WorkOrderReportProductionProcess.KitAssemblyReleaseOrDelete(MQSCWorkOrd& workOrd) in C:\_Development\Acumatica Development\MaxQ Products\Supply Chain Planning\Source\Graph\WorkOrderReportProductionProcess.cs:line 1370
   at MaxQ.Products.SupplyChain.WorkOrderReportProductionProcess.ProcessWOrders(List`1 WOrdersToProcess, Nullable`1 Consolidate) in C:\_Development\Acumatica Development\MaxQ Products\Supply Chain Planning\Source\Graph\WorkOrderReportProductionProcess.cs:line 155
```

What might I be messing up?

- Graph is unrelated to prior actions
- all reads are PXSelectReadonly with SelectSingle
- Directly calling the INDocumentRelease, which is based on the code from  KitAssemblyEntry.cs, near "virtual IEnumerable Release("

Code block:

```
WorkOrderMaint workOrderMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<WorkOrderMaint>();
INKitRegister iNKitRegister = new PXSelectReadonly<INKitRegister, Where<MQSCInKitRegisterExt.wONbr, Equal<Required<MQSCInKitRegisterExt.wONbr>>, And<INKitRegister.released, Equal<False>>>>(workOrderMaint).SelectSingle(workOrd.WONbr);

// using (PXTransactionScope XAct = new PXTransactionScope())
{
    Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "1b2010c2-be46-4da7-8f29-e496a7cc240d"));
    #region Handle the assembly Release
    if (iNKitRegister != null)
    {
        if (workOrd.CloseWO.GetValueOrDefault() && workOrd.QtyToComplete.GetValueOrDefault() == Decimal.Zero)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "fefb4f77-b33c-4ade-a187-b1fb1f7dafba"));
            // If closing the WO, AND none to complete remove existing assembly doc
            KitAssemblyEntry kitAssemblyEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<KitAssemblyEntry>();
            kitAssemblyEntry.Document.Current = new PXSelect<INKitRegister, Where<MQSCInKitRegisterExt.wONbr, Equal<Required<MQSCInKitRegisterExt.wONbr>>, And<INKitRegister.released, Equal<False>>>>(workOrderMaint).SelectSingle(workOrd.WONbr); ;
            kitAssemblyEntry.Document.Delete(kitAssemblyEntry.Document.Current);
            kitAssemblyEntry.Actions.PressSave();
        }
        else
        {
            // Need to Release.  Make sure we don't get an "another process has updated..." message.
            Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "1a4b3f1c-23a8-49ed-943e-722abbfcad60"));
            // At this point, this is throwing error messages about cost (e.g. "Error: 'Total Cost' cannot be empty", "Error: 'Ext. Cost' cannot be empty"
            //  This does NOT happen when do through the screen, or the IN document release process
            // kitAssemblyEntry.release.Press();
            // INRegister doc = PXSelect<INRegister, Where<INRegister.docType, Equal<Required<INRegister.docType>>, And<INRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<INRegister.refNbr>>>>>.Select(workOrderMaint, iNKitRegister.DocType, iNKitRegister.RefNbr);
            INRegister iNRegister = new PXSelectReadonly<INRegister, Where<INRegister.docType, Equal<Required<INRegister.docType>>, And<INRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<INRegister.refNbr>>>>>(workOrderMaint).SelectSingle(iNKitRegister.DocType, iNKitRegister.RefNbr);
            INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(new List<INRegister>() { iNRegister }, false);
            Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "0798d686-a736-4f77-97b7-d808ec082e09"));
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a screen-share session with an Acumatica developer named Dmitry (Last name withheld, up to him if he wishes it shared).

In it, he suggested adding .SelectTimeStamp() prior to the INRegister select (and a few other places).
  And an explicit cache clear, e.g. .Caches["INRegister].ClearQueryCache();

This, it seems, may be needed if you are updating the "Current" record in a non-save event (e.g. In a process, or LongRunningProcess).  It tells the graph to "Refresh" the timestamp from the database.

After adding this as suggested, then rest of the code runs fine.

```
// Generic graph, to allow the selects, no real use other than that.  Chose a simple one for speed
MachineMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<MachineMaint>();
INKitRegister iNKitRegister = new PXSelect<INKitRegister, Where<MQSCInKitRegisterExt.wONbr, Equal<Required<MQSCInKitRegisterExt.wONbr>>, And<INKitRegister.released, Equal<False>>>>(graph).SelectSingle(workOrd.WONbr);
PXTrace.WriteVerbose(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "1b2010c2-be46-4da7-8f29-e496a7cc240d"));
#region Handle the assembly Release
if (iNKitRegister != null)
{
if (workOrd.CloseWO.GetValueOrDefault() && workOrd.QtyToComplete.GetValueOrDefault() == Decimal.Zero)
{
    PXTrace.WriteVerbose(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "fefb4f77-b33c-4ade-a187-b1fb1f7dafba"));
    // If closing the WO, AND none to complete remove existing assembly doc
    KitAssemblyEntry kitAssemblyEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<KitAssemblyEntry>();
    kitAssemblyEntry.Document.Current = new PXSelect<INKitRegister, Where<MQSCInKitRegisterExt.wONbr, Equal<Required<MQSCInKitRegisterExt.wONbr>>, And<INKitRegister.released, Equal<False>>>>(graph).SelectSingle(workOrd.WONbr); ;
    kitAssemblyEntry.Document.Delete(kitAssemblyEntry.Document.Current);
    kitAssemblyEntry.Actions.PressSave();
}
else
{
    // Need to Release.  Make sure we don't get an "another process has updated..." message.
    PXTrace.WriteVerbose(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "1a4b3f1c-23a8-49ed-943e-722abbfcad60"));
    graph.Caches["INRegister"].ClearQueryCache();
    PXTrace.WriteVerbose(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "55a5134a-75fe-4d53-881a-381e2eb8d485"));
    INRegister iNRegister = new PXSelect<INRegister, Where<INRegister.docType, Equal<Required<INRegister.docType>>, And<INRegister.refNbr, Equal<Required<INRegister.refNbr>>>>>(graph).SelectSingle(iNKitRegister.DocType, iNKitRegister.RefNbr);
    using (new PXConnectionScope())
    {
        using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
        {
            PXTrace.WriteVerbose(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "63a21017-41a0-4aa2-8049-959a465fb81f"));
            graph.SelectTimeStamp();
            INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(new List<INRegister>() { iNRegister }, false);
            PXTrace.WriteVerbose(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "08e980a8-b729-4607-b507-69b3ddd15a08"));
            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
    PXTrace.WriteVerbose(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "0798d686-a736-4f77-97b7-d808ec082e09"));
}
```

Comment: Can you by any chance include the modified code in your answer?

Comment: Yes, here it is.  As fair warning, there was a fair bit of refactoring involved while trying to troubleshoot